# Export single column from DynamoDB to csv (or the like)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, export-to-csv

My DynamoDB table is quite large and I don't particularly want to dump the whole thing.  There is one column that I want to test on, so I would like a dump of all of its values that I could have locally to code/test with.  However I am not finding anything that lets me do this.

I found [RazorSQL](https://razorsql.com/) and it semi worked (in the sense that it let me pull down just one column of information from the table but it clearly didn't pull down all the data).

I also found a [Data Pipeline Template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-exportddbtos3.html) on AWS but from what I can tell this will dump the entire table.  I am relatively new to AWS so it's possible I'm not understanding something about pipelines properly.

I'm okay with writing to S3 because I can pull down all the data from there, but anything that gets to my local machine is fine by me

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE:** [This tutorial](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/28549) looks promising but I want to achieve this effect in a non-interactive method

Comment: You may write a Hive script that will do it. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Walkthrough.html . You can run it ad-hoc on AWS EMR or schedule it with AWS DataPipeline as a HiveActivity.

Comment: @mr0re1 this was the closest thing I got to an answer and it ultimately ended up leading me to what I want.  So if you write it up as an answer you'll get the check